# How to transition between views programatically?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am developing a game, and I would like to transition between several views, e.g. Menu Screen, Game Screen, Game Over Screen etc. What would be the easiest way of doing this? I'm not sure if I should use a view stack as the order that the views are shown is not always reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "view stack" you mean a UINavigationController?

The easiest way is to keep references to all of the view controllers somewhere, for example I see people use the application delegate a lot, so your application delegate's class extension would look a little like:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *rootViewController; //this is what gets set as the window's root VC
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *mainScreenViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *gameScreenViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *gameOverScreenViewController;

@end
```

Assume rootViewController just controls a container view for the rest of the app (You would probably actually be well served putting all this logic into the root view controller though...)

Now anytime you need to show a certain screen, call a method like:

```
- (void)switchToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self.rootViewController.view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    [self.rootViewController.view addSubview:viewController.view];
}
```

You can now write methods that are named more memorably like `-switchToGameOverScreen`

```
- (void)switchToGameOverScreen
{
    [self switchToViewController:self.gameOverScreenViewController];
}
```

This basic pattern of view navigation is roughly found in `UITabBarController` and often in views controlled by `UISegmentedControl`s.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. So I shouldn't use any of the storyboard/segue features?

Comment: That sounds like a decent option for you if you don't have to support iOS 4 (I far too often have to, probably why I didn't think to suggest it ;) ). It sort of depends on how complex the flow between the views of your app is and how much work that will take to model in a storyboard vs just do it in code.

Comment: :/ I didn't realize that storyboards were only compatible with iOS5+, when I created a new project it used them by default, and I'm not sure how to do it otherwise.

Comment: Just don't use the storyboards, just have the app delegate load a root view from the nib on launch and set it to be the window's root view controller.

Comment: Ok, looks like I'll have to somewhat rewrite my app, I'm not particularly familiar with doing that so it could take a while. Hopefully your answer works though.

Comment: Well if you've already got a signifiant amount of code using storyboards, maybe it's no longer easiest to do it my way :) Sorry if I steered you wrong!

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a game in Cocos-2d,the transitions between scene can be done like this:

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionCrossFade transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[GameOver scene]]];

Here GameOver is a new scene ,to which it goes after transition effect.

There are many other transitions in cocos-2d for going from one scene to another i.e
0. CCTransitionCrossFade
1. CCTransitionFade
2. CCTransitionFadeBL
3. CCTransitionFadeDown
4. CCTransitionFadeTR
5. CCTransitionFadeUp
6. CCTransitionFlipAngular
7. CCTransitionFlipX
8. CCTransitionFlipY
9. CCTransitionJumpZoom
10. CCTransitionMoveInB
11. CCTransitionMoveInL
12. CCTransitionMoveInT
13. CCTransitionPageTurn
14. CCTransitionRadialCCW
15. CCTransitionRotoZoom
16. CCTransitionShrinkGrow
17. CCTransitionSlideInB
18. CCTransitionSlideInL
19. CCTransitionSlideInR
20. CCTransitionSlideInT
21. CCTransitionSplitCols
22. CCTransitionSplitRows
23. CCTransitionTurnOffTiles
24. CCTransitionZoomFlipAngular
25. CCTransitionZoomFlipX
26. CCTransitionZoomFlipY

Thanks